# How to hide and show the map use angularjs-google-maps in angular 1.x

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm a newbie in angular and I have a problem use angularjs-google-maps [Use this library](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps), I don't know why this happens in my code, here's my code:

```
<div ng-show="!emptyAddress">
    <ng-map center="41,-87"></ng-map>
</div>

<button ng-click="emptyAddress = !emptyAddress"> Show Map </button>
```

But when I press the button the map just shows only gray. [Here's the problem picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hGvp.png)

I try to not hide it and the map is shown. But I need to hide it first.

I have tried to fix it use CSS with property height, opacity, and display. But the map still gray :(

I want to ask about it in his repo, but the issue template told me to ask here first. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-if insted of ng-show/hide`

It will solve issue